# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript

Recibo este error de esta línea:

```
document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change",openImage,false);
```

Alguna idea de como solucionarlo

Comment: ¿Podrias [edit] tu pregunta e incluir el HTML correspondiente? A primera vista parece que no existe un elemento con id "file".

Comment: La cuestión es que hay páginas que no tienen dicho elemento id, y por eso lo muestra indefinido, quisiera saber como puedo condicionar alli para que no me de error cuando el id no exista

Comment: ¿Podrias [edit] tu pregunta e incluir lo que me has comentado? Asi podremos ayudarte mejor. ¿Has intentando comparar `document.getElementById("file")` con `null` en un condicional y despues ejecutar la accion de ser verdadero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por la aclaración que has hecho en los comentarios, una solución a tu problema es verificar que un elemento con el ID específico exista antes de relacionarlo con un evento. Podría ser asi:

```
var archivo = document.getElementById("file");
if(archivo)
{
    archivo.addEventListener("change",openImage,false);
}
```

Esto evita el error y responde tu pregunta, pero es solamente una idea de como podría funcionar, ya que no se que otras situaciones tienes que tomar en cuenta.

Answer (score 10):

Revisa que la vinculación con tu archivo .js se encuentre al final del body en vez de estar en head, así la página carga el árbol del dom y javascript encuentra el elemento que estas reverenciando.

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: Me pasaba lo mismo, y era por esto... por tener la vinculación al inicio del body, y no al final... mil gracias!

Comment: @namas Me sirvio tu ayuda. Muchas Gracias. Solucionado